# How can I test controller for correct XML output with rspec2 and ruby on rails 3?

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, functional-testing, rspec-rails

In rspec1 was a matcher have_tag, which is not in rspec 2 anymore.

How can I simply check an XML output of a RoR controller? XPath would be great...

Answer (score 0):

Use webrat and "have_selector", like this:

```
response.should have_selector("foo") do |tag|
  tag.should have_selector("bar", :content => "Hello World")
end
```

See for example http://www.rubyfocus.biz/blog/2011/01/08/from_have_tag_to_have_selector_in_rspec2_gotchas.html

Comment: The problem is that it automatically prepends an html-tag. It does not treat it as xml. It must not modify the input.

Comment: have_selector prepends nothing. Make sure that in your test, you actually call the XML version, not the HTML version.

Comment: It is XML, content type is right. But with the call of have_selector it prepends html with doctype etc.!